How keep my MacBook on screen saver and prevent it from sleeping, when connected to external monitor and power adapter?
I use my MacBook with an external monitor, and I always keep the lid closed and the power connected. But here’s the thing: when I put the device into screen saver mode in less than a minute, it goes black, and I have to wait for it to connect to the monitor again. This usually takes around a minute, which is super annoying for me.
Before, everything was working fine, but I recently reset my MacBook, and now I can’t turn this feature on, even though I enabled “Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off” and in the lock screen settings, I chose “Never” to turn off the display, whether it’s in battery or adapter.


